# Doctrine (on Ubuntu): What command generate models from database without delete existing models?(I add new tables soo i want update models)

Tags: php, ubuntu, doctrine

Doctrine (on Ubuntu): What command generate models from database without delete existing models?(I add new tables soo i want update models)
Thanks

Comment: I made $ sudo php doctrine-cli.php generate-models-db, is this command create new models or delete all models and then create all models from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Doctrine 1, you'll need to make use of Migrations. Migrations can either be written manually, or auto-generated one of a few different commands:

```
./doctrine generate-migration
./doctrine generate-migrations-db
./doctrine generate-migrations-models
```

Migrations can be a fairly complex topic, so I would [read up on the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en#writing-migration-classes). You may also want to check out this [slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/denderello/symfony-live-2010-using-doctrine-migrations).

If you're using Doctrine 2, things get a little simpler. It doesn't have a Migrations class (yet), but there an easy-to-use command to non-destructively update your db schema:

```
./doctrine orm:schema-tool:update
```

This has worked well for me, but can sometimes fail due to complex foreign key constraints.